# My RESTful Webservice doesnt work.(jersey + tomcat)

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, tomcat

I will create webservice for my application project.But firstly I need to know its working or not, so I applied basic webservice.But

when I run it.I get http 404 error page.

Here my what I did on webservice.

- server = Tomcat 8
- dynamic project name =project name is MovieWebService
- WEB-INF/lib =uploaded all jersey files
- Built package and java class into the src file, and I set the xml file

those are my basic codes. I want to see hello word on tomcat  What is my fault, anyone can help me? By the way sorry my language.
I followed this [document](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/wa-aj-tomcat/) steps until listing 3.

My [path](http://localhost:8080/login).

#### web xml file=

```
<display-name>MovieWebService</display-name>
 <servlet> 
  <servlet-name>MovieWebService REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param> 
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>sample.movie.webservices</param-value> 
  </init-param> 
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet-name>MovieWebService REST Service</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Dont worry starting * side.Just looking like in ths site.Normally its okey in eclipse

#### MovieWebService java file=

```
package sample.movie.webservices;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Path("/hello")
    public class movieWebService { 
     @GET 
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
     public String sayHello() { 
      return "Hello Jersey"; 
     }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080/rest/hello ?

Comment: 404 usually means you are trying to access a remote resource (of your server) that doesn't exist. you define your url patterns as `/rest/*` and your GET resource as `/hello`, so `localhost:8080/appname/rest/hello` should be the correct path. you can also use the tomcat manager to access your apps

Comment: Your code is ok, but you are accessing different url. Try with http://localhost:8080/your-project-name/rest/hello as mentioned in the link you provided ( http://<host>:<port>/<appctx>/rest/hello)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just accessing the wrong path. Do you see the default Tomcat page when going to localhost:8080 ? I think your rest endpoint should be located at http://localhost:8080/MovieWebService/rest/hello then.

Also this tutorial from JavaCodeGeeks should explain everything you are trying to do just fine. Just try to follow it step by step:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure servlet mapping, here change this to your code

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Yourservletname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.yourpackage.yourclass</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Yourservletname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```